# how to generate collocations from text

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm new to NLP & going through an article on collocation. Below is the piece of code mentioned there to generate collocations from the text using nltk. While implementing the code, I'm getting the error shared below. I'm not able to get what I'm doing wrong. I also referred to the official documentation [nltk/collocation](https://www.nltk.org/howto/collocations.html), the approach is different and I'm facing difficulty in following it.

```
from nltk.corpus import genesis
tokens = genesis.words('english-kjv.txt')
gen_text = nltk.Text(tokens)
gen_text.collocations()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-a1efe81f5efd> in <module>
      3 tokens = genesis.words('english-kjv.txt')
      4 gen_text = nltk.Text(tokens)
----> 5 gen_text.collocations()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\text.py in collocations(self, num, window_size)
    442 
    443         collocation_strings = [
--> 444             w1 + " " + w2 for w1, w2 in self.collocation_list(num, window_size)
    445         ]
    446         print(tokenwrap(collocation_strings, separator="; "))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\text.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    442 
    443         collocation_strings = [
--> 444             w1 + " " + w2 for w1, w2 in self.collocation_list(num, window_size)
    445         ]
    446         print(tokenwrap(collocation_strings, separator="; "))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: The code works for me but it looks like you need to pass `num` and `window_size`. What version of nltk are you using? I'm using 3.5. You can find this by printing `nltk.__version__`

Comment: I'm using '3.4.5' version. I tried to pass the default values i.e. num=20 & window_size=2. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59266387/10617438) question. Using `gen_text.collocation_list()` might solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, it worked for me.